# Flash disable it self automatically on Firefox

Tags: firefox, flash

I'm on Windows 8.1, 64. Firefox ver. 46 and Shockwave Flash 21.0 r0

I don't understand why is this happens... I tried to re-install it, but it happens over and over. I go to the add-ons section and set it to Always Activate, but then in about some hours it disable it self again... very annoying. Why is this happening and what should I do?

Comment: Usually when this happens, Firefox blocks Flash due to unsolved security issues. Always make sure you have the latest version of flash.

Comment: But this is the latest version. I also tried to re-download it twice from adobe website. The version is the same for my windows 8.1 64bit. But thank you for trying to help me LPChip

Comment: What is the Flash full version (click on "More" in the plugin listing)? It should be "Shockwave Flash 21.0.0.213". If not you don't have the current version. If it is correct, you might add a screenshot of the disabled notification screen.

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's 21.0.0.213. And here is the list I found, and it says it is the latest version: http://www.adobe.com/il_en/software/flash/about/

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem; even though I had the latest Flash installed, every time I told Firefox to enable Flash it would be disabled again after a browser restart. I believe I have fixed it with these steps:

1. Download, but do not run the installer for my OS and browser version: https://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/otherversions/
2. Shut down *all* browsers
3. Manually uninstall Flash in the Windows Programs and Features
4. Run the installer I had downloaded (you may have to right-click on the installer and select "Run as Administrator")
5. Start Firefox and ensure Flash is enabled

Comment: Also, step 4 generally requires right-clicking on the installer and running it as administrator.

Comment: @fixer1234 - It should prompt for Admin rights with the UAC.

Comment: It typically doesn't prompt; it just fails to install, at least on some versions of Windows (unless this behavior is determined by the UAC setting).  I discovered this by trial and error after numerous failed attempts to update Flash on several computers.  Then I found the same advice on a question here where somebody else had run into the same problem.  Until fairly recently, running the installer as administrator wasn't required.

Comment: @fixer1234 - Odd, it's always prompted me with the UAC. Still, I updated my answer.

Comment: The multiple version problem is another thing that seems to be recent.  You beat me to the answer; I upvoted yours.  :-)